# Annotation based service activator not using custom comparator in priority queue

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-integration

I have a setup with Spring Integration Queues connecting together various Java objects. The queue configuration is set up in a spring-config.xml, and I have the service activator as an Annotation. The messages all get through fine, but it is not using the custom comparator at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd">

<int:channel id="testGeneratedChannel">
    <int:priority-queue comparator="myComparator" capacity="500"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="myComparator" class="com.my.server.myChannelComparitor"></bean>

</beans>
```

The end point is annotated like this:

```
@Configuration
@Service
public class TestEndPoint
{

    @Async("myOneAtATimeExecutor")
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testGeneratedChannel")
    public void consumeMessage(Message<Price> pr) {

        System.out.println("Timestamp: " + pr.getPayload().getTimestamp().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the whole configuration with all Java, as outlined in this post (http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/configuring-spring-integration-channels-without-xml/) and it works correctly.

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean
    public PriorityChannel testGeneratedChannel() {
        return new PriorityChannel(new PriceChannelComparitor());
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

}
```

and then in the main class:

```
PriorityChannel channel = (PriorityChannel)     context.getBean(PriorityChannel.class);
    MessageHandler handler = new TestEndPoint();
    PollingConsumer consumer = new PollingConsumer(channel, handler);     
    consumer.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    consumer.setTrigger(trigger);
    consumer.setBeanFactory(context);    
    consumer.start();
```

and then changing the end point to a implement handleMessage

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message<?> arg0) throws MessagingException {

    Message<Price> pr = (Message<Price>) arg0;
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + pr.getPayload().getTimestamp().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
    // etc......
}
```

The main thing I see that is different between the pure Java approach and the Annotation one, is that there is a specific Poller defined. Looking at the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#x4.0-poller-annotation it appears that I should be able to set a Poller in the annotation, but whenever I try I get an error in STS saying "The annotation @Poller is disallowed for this location".

Can anyone please suggest a way to use the Annotation based approach that works?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing: `...rewriting... and it works correctly` Vs. `Can anyone please suggest a way to use the Annotation based approach that works?`. Where are you adding the `@Poller`, it needs to be `poller = @Poller(...)`; you don't need to create a `PollingConsumer` manually. What makes you believe the comparator is not being used with XML; we have test cases for that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/channel/config/priorityChannelParserTests.xml#L14).

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the Poller format. I changed that and am getting to the root of the error. When I declare the channel as a bean in Java, everything now works with the annotation based method. However with the XML based method, I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: A '@Poller' should not be specified for Annotation-based endpoint, since 'testGeneratedChannel' is a SubscribableChannel (not pollable)`. Even removing the comparator to leave ` <int:channel id="testGeneratedChannel">
  <int:priority-queue capacity="500"/>
 </int:channel>` I get the error.

Comment: If you are using XML you should not have a `@Poller` on the annotation. It might be causing some early unexpected initialization of the service activator. What version of Spring Integration are you using?